# How to run Unreal blueprint nodes on BeginPlay that depend on another blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I need blueprint **A** to run nodes in BeginPlay which rely on a variable in blueprint **B**, but that variable is null until set in **B**'s BeginPlay function. Of course, **A**'s BeginPlay could run before **B**'s and I would run into errors. I can think of two ways to get around this, but neither feel like a proper approach:

1. In **A**'s BeginPlay, add a Delay node with a second or less duration in the hopes that **B**'s variable has been initialized by then. It seems like this could easy break things and isn't smooth.
2. Have an Event Dispatcher in **B** called "VariableSet". **A** binds an event to it in BeginPlay and that event runs the dependent code. This usually works but I haven't heard of anyone doing this.

Is there a proven, documented method to avoid null pointers in BeginPlay?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using [the construction graph](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/UserConstructionScript/) got initialising your required variables.

Comment: @George I don't think that would fit my needs in this case. Often the variable is a reference to an actor or component spawned during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the similar problem in the past.
And in my case I just used **Event Dispatchers**. I'm not too proud of that aproach but It did a job.

- Parent is calling **ED** at the end of BeginPlay execution flow
- Child is binding **ED** to CustomEvent at the beggining of its own BeginPlay execution flow
- When Parent's BeginPlay is finished (which calls **ED**), logic in Child's CustomEvent runs

[image]

For me it worked really well because one Parent had a lot of Childs and these Childs had their own Childs, etc, etc...
and due to Dispatchers and Events I was able to easily track what was going on.

Comment: This seems like the most correct approach. It's more foolproof than the Delay method. Thanks.